# Error deploying Meteor app to Heroku - how to change NODE version

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku

I received this error message when deploying a meteor app to HEROKU while the HEROKU build itself was successful: 
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I believe it has to do with the version of NODE in the project being incompatible. Currently the project shows the below (I manually changed this in the project file to match a version of NODE the HEROKU command line prompted. 
meteor/local/build/.node_version.txt : v8.3.0

```
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (not-found)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/build_716b8c55d4775b8c4db0d8c2018f489f/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        [bcrypt] Success: "/tmp/build_716b8c55d4775b8c4db0d8c2018f489f/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
remote:        added 195 packages in 5.765s
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 44.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://missionary-expediters-app.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/missionary-expediters-app.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
➜  Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application git:(master) heroku logs
2018-01-16T03:58:30.407001+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:58:30.407001+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:58:30.641875+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:58:30.641875+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:59:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:59:59.490555+00:00 app[api]: Deploy f900129c by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:59:59.510788+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T03:59:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-01-16T04:00:03.035774+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-01-16T03:59:59.490555+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user angelica@seaworthy.tech
2018-01-16T04:00:05.155112+00:00 app[web.1]: > Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application@ start /app
2018-01-16T04:00:05.155090+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-01-16T04:00:05.168004+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-01-16T04:00:05.155113+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2018-01-16T04:00:05.155114+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-01-16T04:00:05.168910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-01-16T04:00:05.162754+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2018-01-16T04:00:05.171081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-01-16T04:00:05.171090+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-01-16T04:00:05.168907+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-16T04:00:05.168911+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-01-16T04:00:05.170446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application@ start: `meteor run`
2018-01-16T04:00:05.171096+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-16T04:00:05.171091+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application@ start script.
2018-01-16T04:00:05.176036+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-01-16T04:00:05.175802+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-01-16T04:00:05.176169+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-16T04_00_05_172Z-debug.log
2018-01-16T04:00:05.242382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-01-16T04:00:05.244044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-01-16T04:00:05.230580+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-01-16T04:00:08.424396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2018-01-16T04:00:10.625159+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-01-16T04:00:10.612429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-01-16T04:00:10.540497+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-01-16T04:00:10.540515+00:00 app[web.1]: > Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application@ start /app
2018-01-16T04:00:10.540516+00:00 app[web.1]: > meteor run
2018-01-16T04:00:10.540517+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-01-16T04:00:10.546730+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2018-01-16T04:00:10.552451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-01-16T04:00:10.552644+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-01-16T04:00:10.552794+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-01-16T04:00:10.552930+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-01-16T04:00:10.554224+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application@ start: `meteor run`
2018-01-16T04:00:10.554544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-01-16T04:00:10.554414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-01-16T04:00:10.554639+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Missionary-Expediters-Web-Application@ start script.
2018-01-16T04:00:10.559460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2018-01-16T04:00:10.559334+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-01-16T04:00:10.554754+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-01-16T04:00:10.559520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-16T04_00_10_556Z-debug.log
```

Any suggestions on how to get the app up and running? It works on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem with the node version, because Meteor I know supports 8.9.3, and 8.9.4 shouldn't be significantly different.

If you read the dump above you'll see these lines:

```
2018-01-16T04:00:05.168910+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-01-16T04:00:05.162754+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: meteor: not found
2018-01-16T04:00:05.171081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

Which is telling you that the command `meteor` is not found - perhaps you didn't install meteor to your heroku instance ? There is a guide here on how to set up Heroku - did you do something like that already?

https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234

See section 5:

> 5. Set a Meteor buildpack for your Heroku instance

`heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git`

> What is a buildpack? It’s a collection of scripts that prepares your
>   code for execution by the Heroku dyno manager. Heroku’s cedar stack
>   has no default language/framework support, so we use a buildpack to
>   determine/specify what kind of framework we wanted to build on.
>
> What is cedar then? It’s a polyglot environment, which means it has
>   native support for many popular languages and frameworks (e.g. Rails,
>   Node.js, Java, PHP). It also serves as Heroku’s default runtime stack
>   (cedar-14).

Comment: Wow.. thank you so much Mikkel. Issue solved and new things were learned from your explanation!!